# How change characters to asterisk on TEdit onkeyup event?

Tags: delphi

my client requested to me for make a "effect" where each time that release any key of keyboard, change this character to asterisk on field.

How do this in Delphi?

I have in Html + Javascript like [this](http://www.floyddems.org/plugins/system/mod/x000000/teste.html). .js code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/TmYmCwHJ).

Comment: What happens when you select a few asterisks and press delete with that js code?

Comment: Link of question was edited, see how i'm wanting on link now.

Comment: Still won't work. Type '1', '2', '3', press backspace, type '4'. You'll submit 123, password is 124.

Comment: I'm not have interest on submit, only on keyup event that change to asterisk. How do this in Delphi?

Comment: Er, surely you care about what the content of the edit is? And if you want a password, why not use the password mask feature of the edit control

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel? HTML already provides `<input type=password>`, it merely happens not to use an asterisk but another placeholder character. Delphi provides the same functionality built-in as part of `TEdit`.

Comment: @Hvd, Mas eu preciso mudar cada personagem para asterisco no evento keyup. Como fazer isso em Delphi?

Comment: @Saulo I don't even know which language that is, let alone understand what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: Well, in `passwordchar` property of `TEdit` component is possible set to asterisk, but this way stays permanently with asterisk, and i want with asterisk only when release each key ( like show example of link above on my question ).

Comment: I think what you want is to simulate password entry on mobile OS.

Comment: No @SertacAkyuz, i want make equals keyup event of link above. Exists this possibility in Delphi?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't. An edit has an OnKeyUp event handler, and you can replace its text.

Comment: Undertand how i want >> **1-** press a letter, **2-** appears this letter on TEdit normally, **3-** change this letter to asterisk when occurs keyup event.

Comment: I think that based on down votes above, not is possible make in Delphi as i described on last comment and as is on example that i left on question :-)

Comment: @Saulo "2- appears this letter on TEdit normally," -- That part is completely unclear from your question and I recommend you edit it to include it.

Comment: @Saulo People don't generally down-vote questions just because something is not possible. Yes there are exceptions; but it's more likely your questions was considered unclear or poorly researched. (_NOTE I'm not saying that is what happened; just pointing out possible opinions others might have had._) I actually like the fact that you're looking at ways to improve your password interface; personally I consider the idea of a password mask somewhat silly when no one apart from me has sight of my monitor.

Comment: Thanks for support @Craig Young :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below simulates the behavior of the js code with the difference backspace is also handled.

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Edit1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  private
    FEditText: string;

procedure TForm2.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = ^H then
    SetLength(FEditText, Length(FEditText) - 1)
  else
    FEditText := FEditText + Key;
end;

procedure TForm2.Edit1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Edit1.Text := StringOfChar('*', Length(Edit1.Text));
  Edit1.SelStart := Length(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

`FEditText` is the equivalent of `df[0].Value` in js code, the actual value that is typed.

Note that there's no option to reset the text, as there is none in the js code.

Comment: Very nice @SertacAkyuz, was it that i tried say to you in all my comments above :D. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I see you've already found it, but to note it anyway `StringOfChar` is in 'strutils.pas'.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve what you want with the standard Delphi controls.

The VCL edit control uses the feature of the underlying Windows EDIT control to mask input characters for "Password" type edit controls.  The behaviour is therefore determined by the Windows (OS) control, not Delphi itself.

You could try to get the effect you need by using a non-password field and handling key events to replace characters as required with asterisks or any other masking character, but you would also need to separately maintain the intended content of the edit control.

This would almost certainly be easier to implement as a custom edit control, rather than trying to customize the behaviour of a standard edit control with events.

I suspect that the implementation of a custom control is not the solution you are after however.

Comment: Agreed, there's a lot to watch out for. One would have to accurately mimic edit controls behaviour to correctly track the internal string.